# passport bookshelf is not inserting user into database

Tags: postgresql, passport.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using passport with [bookshelf](https://bookshelfjs.org), and im having issues inserting a user in the database.

I'm using postman, and it shows that a user has been added to the db, but its not.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be much information about bookshelf, passport, and postgres used together. So it makes finding solutions like this hard.

**routes/users**

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('register', (err, user, info) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        if(info !== undefined){
            console.log(info.message)
            res.status(403).send(info.message)
        }else{
            req.logIn(user, err  => {
                const data = {
                    username: req.body.username.trim(), 
                    password: req.body.password.trim(),
                    email: req.body.email.trim()
                }
                console.log(data);
                User.forge({
                    username: data.username
                }).fetch().then( (user) => {

                    console.log('user creatd in db');
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message:'user created'
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**passport.js**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
import User from '../models/User';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import JWTstrag from 'passport-jwt';
import ExtracJWT from 'passport-jwt';

const JWTstrategy  = JWTstrag.Strategy
const ExtractJWT = ExtracJWT.ExtractJwt
const Local = LocalStrategy.Strategy


const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
};



passport.use('jwt', new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    try{
        User.forge({username: jwt_payload._id})
        .fetch()
        .then( (user) => {
            if(user){
                console.log('user found in db in passport');
                done(null, user)
            }else{
                console.log('user not found in db');
                done(null, false)
            }
        })
    } catch(err){
        done(err)
    }

}))


passport.use(
    'register',
    new Local(
      {
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        // passReqToCallback: true,
        session: false,
      },
      (req, username, password, done) => {
        try {
            User.forge({username: username}, {email: req.body.email}).fetch().then(user => {
            if (user != null) {
              console.log('username or email already taken');
              return done(null, false, {
                message: 'username or email already taken',
              });
            } else {
              bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then(hashedPassword => {
                const user = new User({
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    email: req.body.email
                })
                user.save().then( () => {
                    res.status(200).send('user created')
                    return done(null, user);
                })
              });
            }
          });
        } catch (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
      },
    ),
);

// passport.use(new Local ( (username, password, done) => {
//     User.findOne({username: username} , (err, user) =>{
//         if(err){
//             return done(err)
//         }
//         if(!user){
//             return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect username."})
//         }

//         if(!user.validPassword(password)){
//             return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'})
//         }

//         return done (null, user)
//     })
// }))


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    User
      .forge({id: user})
      .fetch()
      .then((usr) => {
        done(null, usr);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
});
```

**main.js**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import userRoute from './routes/users';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';
import './config/passport';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
// For React Stuff if need be
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// you need body parser urlencoded so passport will not give a Missing Credentials error
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 

app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave:false,
  cookie: {   maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },  // 30 days
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.use('/users', userRoute);

app.use(() => (req, res, next)  =>{
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});


//build mode
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'));
// })


// module.parent prevents the 
// Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use error when unit testing
if(!module.parent){
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
  );
 }

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, there were a number of errors.

One being the

> done is not a function

Which will be fixed by uncommenting

```
passReqToCallback: true,
```

two being res thats not supposed to be in the passport.js file but route file.

so remove

`res.status(200).send('user created')`

Now everything should be working.

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(
    'register',
    new Local(
      {
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
        session: false,
      },
      (req, username, password, done) => {
        try {
            User.forge({username: username}, {email: req.body.email}).fetch().then(user => {
            if (user != null) {
              console.log('username or email already taken');
              return done(null, false, {
                message: 'username or email already taken',
              });
            } else {
              bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then(hashedPassword => {
                const user = new User({
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    email: req.body.email
                })
                user.save().then( () => {
                    return done(null, user);
                })
              });
            }
          });
        } catch (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
      },
    ),
);
```

**routes/users**

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('register', (err, user, info) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        if(info !== undefined){
            console.log(info.message)
            res.status(403).send(info.message)
        }else{
            req.logIn(user, err  => {
                const data = {
                    username: req.body.username.trim(), 
                    password: req.body.password.trim(),
                    email: req.body.email.trim()
                }
                console.log(data);
                User.forge({
                    username: data.username
                }).fetch().then( (user) => {
                    console.log('user creatd in db');
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message:'user created'
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```